# Sanitizing strings with (intentionally) difficult characters

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have a program that parses user input.  I was getting errors relating to \0000 in the unicode string (`unsupported Unicode escape sequence`), so I did some investigation and found:

`A_real_string_\x03\x04\x00\x06\x00\x03\x08\t\x01\x03 \ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd`

I would like to remove things like this (particularly `\x00`) from the string without dropping support for international characters.  What's a good approach?

Edit: I think what I would really like to do is remove the \x00 and everything after it.  How could I do that?

Comment: If you do not say what you want to remove and what you want to keep, it will be hard for others to guess...

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Read again and you will notice i did mention particularly \x00

Comment: I read it, but as you sais *things like this(**particurarly** \00)*, I understood you want to remove `\00` *and others I could not guess*. I want not sure that you only wanted to remove `\00`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Sorry for the confusion :)  Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove some characters from a string, just iterate the string and skip the unwanted ones, then join back the individual characters.

Assuming your unicode string is called `ustr`, you could use:

```
u''.join([ c for ustr in a if c not in u'\00'])
```

(if you later want to remove other characters, say `\01` add them to the not in part : `...not in u'\00\01')`

This should work both for Python 2.x and 3.x

---

If you want to remove everything after first `\00`, just `find` it in the original string:

```
ix = ustr.find(u'\00')
filtered = ustr if ix == -1 else ustr[:ix]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`codecs.decode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode) with non-strict error behaviour, i.e.:

```
codecs.decode('string', 'utf8', 'ignore')
```

However that will give you a unicode string. To make that into your previous format of a bytes string, you just use the `.encode` method of the decoded string.

Comment: Try replacing/translating the string (the latter should be more efficient if you are working with a lot of replacements) with [string.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20translate#str.translate) before passing them to the decode function.